# Prims Algorithm : Runtime Error (C++)

Tags: c++, graph, prims-algorithm

I was trying to implement the algorithm by myself, but I am getting a runtime error upon execution and i am quite unable to figure out why.

The code is split into three parts :
A) Storing the Graph in the form of an adjacency matrix, where a cell(i,j), if 0 represents no edge is present between the two vertices, where as non zero entry signifies the presence of an edge and the entry equals the weight of the edge from i to j.

B) Creating 3 arrays to hold weights, parents and to track the visited vertices, and in the First while loop of building the MST, I call the getMin function to provide me with the minimum weight amongst the non visited edges, then I update the weights of its corresponding neighbours if they are lower than their previously assigned weights, and continue this till the counter i becomes equal to n.

C)The last step is to print the MST which is quite straightforward.

Here is the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

int getMin(int* weights, int n, bool* visited) {
    int minimum = INT_MAX;
    int minIndex = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(weights[i] < minimum && !visited[i]) {
            minimum = weights[i];
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}

int main() {
    int n, e;
    cin >> n >> e;
    //Creating an adjacency matrix to store Graph
    int** edges = new int*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        edges[i] = new int[n];
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            //Initializing each entry as 0(False) for now
            edges[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    //Taking input of edges
    for(int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        int f,s,w;
        cin >> f >> s >> w;
        edges[f][s] = edges[s][f] = w; //Storing weights as the entries
    }

    //Array 1 for tracking the visited vertices
    bool* visited = new bool[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        visited[i] = false;
    }
    //Array 2 for maintaining weights
    int* weights = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            //Treating 0 as source vertex
            weights[i] = 0;
        }
        else {
            weights[i] = INT_MAX;
        }
    }
    //Array 3 for maintaining parents of each vertex
    //Will be helpful in tracing the MST after n - 1 edges are added
    int* parent = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            //Source vertex has no parent
            parent[i] = -1;
        }
        else {
            //INT_MIN symbolizing no parents yet
            parent[i] = INT_MIN;
        }
    }
    //Building the MST
    int i = 0;
    while(i < n) {
        int minimum = getMin(weights, n, visited);
        visited[minimum] = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(edges[minimum][j] != 0 && !visited[j]) {
                if(edges[minimum][j] < weights[j]) {
                    weights[j] = edges[minimum][j];
                    parent[j] = minimum;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    //Printing the MST
    int k = 0;
    while(k < n) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(parent[j] == k) {
                cout << k << " " << j << " " << edges[i][j] << endl;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the console log.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to execute your code one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables on each step, until your program crashes, what observations did you make?